# eBay : what value should be set for ShippingCostPaidByOption for return policy API

Tags: ebay-api

I'm working with ebay Trading API for listing the product but after I'm stucking in it where i need to set value for a option in `Return policy Type API`, I need to set `ShippingCostPaidByOption` with value either Paid by buyer or Paid by Seller?

Similarly I need to set `RefundOption` value either `Money` or Money or item replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the applicable *RefundOption* and *ShippingCostPaidByOption* values, call *GeteBayDetails* with *DetailName* set to *ReturnPolicyDetails*, and then look for the **ReturnPolicyDetails.Refund.RefundOption** and **ReturnPolicyDetails.ShippingCostPaidBy.ShippingCostPaidByOption** fields in the response. The value of the fields can be used in your *AddItem* request.

The following example can be used as a request to *GeteBayDetails* using the eBay [API](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/) explorer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GeteBayDetailsRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>[ADD YOU OWN AUTH TOKEN</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <DetailName>ReturnPolicyDetails</DetailName>
</GeteBayDetailsRequest>
```

A typical response will look like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeteBayDetailsResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <ReturnPolicyDetails>
        <Refund>
            <RefundOption>MoneyBackOrExchange</RefundOption>
            <Description>Money back or exchange (buyer's choice)</Description>
        </Refund>
    </ReturnPolicyDetails>
    <ShippingCostPaidBy>
        <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
        <Description>Buyer</Description>
    </ShippingCostPaidBy>
    </ReturnPolicyDetails>
</GeteBayDetailsResponse>
```